# List group item is not showing the color, how to fix that?

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

This is my html file:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-J6qa4849blE2+poT4WnyKhv5vZF5SrPo0iEjwBvKU7imGFAV0wwj1yYfoRSJoZ+n" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-wfSDF2E50Y2D1uUdj0O3uMBJnjuUD4Ih7YwaYd1iqfktj0Uod8GCExl3Og8ifwB6" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Cras justo odio</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Morbi leo risus</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Porta ac consectetur ac</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">Vestibulum at eros</li>
</ul>

<ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item">Dapibus ac facilisis in</li>
li class="list-group-item list-group-item-primary">This is a primary list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-secondary active">This is a secondary list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">This is a success list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-danger">This is a danger list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-warning">This is a warning list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-info">This is a info list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-light">This is a light list group item</li>
  <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-dark">This is a dark list group item</li>
</ul>
```

My css file: [path](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/uday1kiran/TodoProject/master/todo/static/todo/assets/css/bootstrap.css)

Reference link used: bootstrap [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/list-group/)

But the list group items are not getting colored as below.

[image: coloring]

Please suggest.

Comment: The CSS file you linked to in your question is for Bootstrap v3.0.1. The style you’re looking to use is for Bootstrap v4. Try a different source, such as the [CDN version](https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css) recommended by Bootstrap.

Comment: Yeah I tried that with bootstrap 4 but it is removing other styles. Like header is getting a gap on top of it

Comment: It would be good if you could post enough of your code (maybe using the Code Snippet function) so the header gap can be seen. — Also, your code is missing an opening angle bracket in the second list group.

Comment: That one I changed already. And the template file is base.html in the repo: https://github.com/uday1kiran/TodoProject/tree/master/todo/templates/todo